# Why must we port ROMs

Tags: acpi, hal

We can install windows on a range of machines, but when one attempts to flash a ROM on another android device, it doesn't work. I assume this is because the kernel and system optimisations are only compatible with the specific SOC, battery. The BIOS informs windows of the capabilities of different devices through ACPI tables and it works with a range of hardware. Is there a reason why there isn't a hardware abstraction layer in the usual sense on android devices, is it just  the manufacturers gain?

Comment: Most of your assumptions are incorrect. You can't "flash" ROM.  Flash memory is not *"ROM"*.  Android does have HW abstraction layers.  The fact that Android runs on a wider range (*range* not number) of devices than Windows proves that point.  The issue is that the image is fully customized to the hardware.  Whereas a Windows installation silently configures itself and tries to auto-install all necessary device drivers for you.  That's why you have to be connected to the Internet during install.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/lifehacker.com/how-to-flash-a-rom-to-your-android-phone-30885281/amp  Rom has just come to be a synonym for a mobile OS with a custom skin in this case

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Is there a reason why there isn't a hardware abstraction layer in the usual sense on android devices

Economic reasons:

- Android devices are typically single-board ARM-based devices with all hardware embedded, and that hardware won't change over the lifetime of the device.  The user will typically just buy a new device.
- Android is an "embedded" type of operating system.  Hardware that runs Android is typically not expected to support or run any other operating system.
- ACPI is a complex standard that's difficult to implement.

For things like phones, time to market is worth more to companies than developing standards that other companies use.  Windows, wanting to sell operating systems that work on diverse Intel-based hardware vendors, obviously preferred to have the standard (and both Intel and Microsoft had a hand in designing ACPI.)

Technical reasons:

- Windows relies a lot on the firmware (BIOS or UEFI) during startup and during operation.  Linux can be configured to not rely on firmware at all after it is loaded, and for ARM platforms, this is probably typical.

  - So simpler (and less friendly) schemes can be used with Linux, either things like device trees or just having drivers built in to the kernel that know where their hardware is on the platform without needing to do any discovery.

> but when one attempts to flash a ROM on another android device, it doesn't work

- The bootloader in Android devices is often configured to only load a signed image - if the image containing the OS is not signed it won't work.
- The bootloader itself is often very hardware specific and built for a specific board.  (You can't take a BIOS for one model laptop and expect it to work on a different model laptop either - you would, as the OEM, have to build a new BIOS for a new platform). If the ROM image contains the bootloader and you try to run it on the wrong platform, it will probably not work.
- The Linux drivers for the hardware devices in many Android devices is not open source.  Includes things like display, Wifi, cellular.  So they won't work with later kernel versions.  Likely this is the primary reason different ROMs won't work, because the kernel version is a later, better one, but no newer driver is available (and one can't be built without the source code).
- The command line options passed to the booting kernel may be crucial - for example, those options may tell the kernel to avoid certain memory ranges that cause the system to lockup if accessed.

Comment: These answers to the OP's questions are wrong (e.g. Android does have HW abstraction), and the reasoning is also wrong.  The OP equates the writing of the Android flash image to a Windows installation, which performs a system configuration.  There is no configuration when the Android flash image is "installed".  The equivalent Windows operation would be the transplanting of an existing Windows system on a HDD/SSD from one PC to some other PC, and expecting it to boot flawlessly.  The OP is comparing *installations* that are like apples to oranges, and this "answer" fails to point that out.

Comment: You got a good point about how flashing a ROM in the manner OP describes is like transplanting an existing Windows.  I know about the "vendor interface" HAL in Oreo but it's not related to how ACPI on x86 tries to present hardware - the Android HAL is operating system level, not firmware level.